# ReferenceError: fetch is not defined when importing from discord.js (v14) in ts-jest tests

Tags: jestjs, discord.js, ts-jest

I'm running the following ts-jest code:

```
import { Client, GatewayIntentBits } from "discord.js";

let client: Client;
beforeEach(async () => {
  client = new Client({ intents: GatewayIntentBits.Guilds });
});

describe("guildCreate", () => {
  it("empty DB: call with new options", async () => {
    // check before 1st fn call
    expect(client.guilds.cache.size).toEqual(0);
  });
});
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Test suite failed to run
                                                                                                        
ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@discordjs/rest/src/web.ts:3:20)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js:4:18)
```

Initialising the Client works fine in my code. But, fails when in jest for discordJs (v14).

Comment: What's your Node version?

Comment: @VLAZ My node version is v20.10.0.

Comment: OK, I suspected it's older and `fetch()` wasn't available but it's definitely there in 20.

Comment: @VLAZ The library works fine when I do a live test with the discord client. It only fails when I use it in jest. I'm not sure if that helps or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the answer is to add the following code to my `jest.config.js` file:

```
globals: { fetch: global.fetch },
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if your bot runs truly on this node version?

I had a similar issue a while a go where it always to another version even though I changed and uninstalled it.

For me it fixed it when I switched in the package json from:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
  },


  "scripts": {
    "start": "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/bin/node src/index.js",
  },
```

Maybe you need to change the directory